# The upper bound of the number of points of a convex hull formed by external co-tangents of circles

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Consider the following problem: Given a rope to surround some circles, and minimize the length of the rope.
In order to solve the problem, we shall calculate all external co-tangents of these circles, and use these points to get a convex hull. Then enumerate each edge of the convext hull to check whether it is part of the rope. The rope will be composed of such edges and some arcs.
So the crucial problem is to estimate the number of points of the convex hull. If the number of points can reach $\Theta(n^2)$ where $n$ is the number of circles, the algorithm will be slow. But I guess the number of points is $\Theta(n)$ from experiments.
Can we prove the upper bound is $\Theta(n)$? Or just construct an example to overthrow the claim.